# (iphone sdk) When I use CGAffineTransform (such as CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation) does that actually "move" the frame?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, rendering, transform

Or does it just change where it's rendered?  I have performed this transform and I think the object's frame's origin's y position stays the same.

Comment: Also, after my transform takes place, can I have some code take affect?  For instance, I want a view to animate down and then I want to change it's height.  But right now, it just changes the height and then animates down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens is that it just renders the frame in a different position.  That's why the position values don't change.

Also, to have something occur after the animation, I will use a timer to run a piece of code after the animation.